# Why is NSURLSession causing my controller to be retained?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure why my NSURLSession is retaining the controller if I am using weakSelf.   I know the block still gets executed regardless, but when I set breakpoints in the delegate methods (i.e. didReceiveData), I see self is not nil even though the controller was dismissed already.

Would appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks!

Please see my code snippet below

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                 delegate:weakSelf
                                            delegateQueue: nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    [task resume];

    [weakSelf.imagesAndTasks setObject:image forKey:task];

});
```

Comment: Your `viewcontroller` object should be a `strong` type so it will not retained. Try this!!

Comment: Fixed it by: 1. moving configuration and session out of the block and in viewDidLoad 2. calling session invalidateAndCancel prior to dismissing my view controller.